# Banno Integration Question (Consumer Endpoint: PUT: name)- jhaEnterprise Workflow Integration

Tags: workflow, banno-digital-toolkit, jackhenry-jxchange

ENDPOINT: https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/accounts/details/#/Account%20Information/put_users__userId__accounts__accountId__name

I am testing and developing a workflow to modify the account alias/account friendly name as it is presented on the customer facing side. Our use case is a product type reserved for teens and young adults and once they turn 21, EWF modifies the ScCode. I am working to modify the customer facing friendly name associated with that account but getting a 403 error. I thought it may be permissions related as the documentation states that the service account requires "Read/Write" permissions. My previous POC for EWF/Banno integration (RDC approval automation) required "View Everything". To my understanding, we've modified the permissions to allow updating the "name" via PUT API but continue to get the 403 error. (Related to Jack Case 14548353). EWF support indicated that they internally are getting the same error from their test environment. Case transferred to Banno support where they directed me to Stack Overflow.

Permissions set according to documentation. Passing URI with required fields. Input JSON string with "Name" element for PUT.

Comment: Apologies, it is unclear which _specific_ API endpoint you're referencing. Can you do us a favor and include a link to the API you're using via a link to the docs on JackHenry.Dev?

Comment: https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/accounts/details/#/Account%20Information/put_users__userId__accounts__accountId__name

Comment: Can you provide an example of the fully-qualified URL that you are using for the endpoint? (You can redact info like the `{userId}` and `{accountId}`, but seeing the full URL is helpful to understand what might be happening).

Comment: The goBank.ffb.com was configured on JX (ewfManagementConsole) by Banno Support as the consumer endpoint opening URL. I am able to GET user info from that endpoint but unable to PUT. 
PUT https://gobank.ffb.com/a/consumer/api/v0/users/{userId}/accounts/{accountId}/name

Comment: If called from the *Consumer API* then that would be `PUT https://gobank.ffb.com/a/consumer/api/v0/users/{userId}/accounts/{accountId}/name`, which would require the OAuth scope `https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/accounts.readwrite`. If it's being called via the Consumer API without that scope, that would explain the HTTP 403 Forbidden behavior. You can see the list of scopes via the `.well-known` OpenID Connect Discovery endpoint https://gobank.ffb.com/a/consumer/api/v0/oidc/.well-known/openid-configuration.

Comment: Is the call being made via the *Consumer API*?

Comment: To my understanding that endpoint does not exist from the ADMIN API, so yes, that is a consumer API endpoint. I am attempting to automate when modifications to the ProdCode (ScCode) are made within SilverLake Core that the customer facing name modify to the product type.

Comment: Can you verify that your authorization URL is passing in the `https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/accounts.readwrite` OAuth scope? We have an example of how the authorization URL works in https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/quickstarts/authenticationcommandline/

Comment: This may be a limitation of jhaEnterprise Workflow (EWF). The Consumer and Admin API opening of the URL was configured by Banno and EWF support. The External REST Service tool allows me to pass the {UserId} and {AccountId} as variables to drill to the specific user BUT there is not a way, to my knowledge, to create the OAUTH scope from EWF for each workflow instance. IF possible, need to work with EWF support and add to EWF documentation for clarity. NOTE: There are Header Key and Header Value options within the REST tool.